# Question about subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$, where $n>5$.
How many subsets $B\subseteq A$, satisfy the condition that $B\cap\{1,2,3\}=\{1,2\}$?

So we know that $1$ and $2$ are found in B.
I think the answer is 3.

$\{1\}\subseteq A$
$\{2\}\subseteq A$
$\{1,2\}\subseteq A$
Am I right? 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you mean sub*sets*.  Group has a specific meaning in mathematics involving a set and a binary operation

Comment: you're right, it's lost in translation, I'm editing.

Comment: 1. "subgroup" has a meaning in math which you don't mean. Better to write "subset". 2. What about $B=\{\,1,2,4\,\}$? I'm not sure either one of us really understands your question. 3. Please learn how to format math on this site. There's help via the help menu.

Comment: You have edited, but "subgroup" is still in the title.

Comment: fixed,can you try to answer the question please

Comment: I edited the question myself to make it easier to read. Let me know if there are any problems with my edits. There's a correct answer below, but to be clear, two of the sets you mentioned do not satisfy that condition. $\{1\}\cap A=\{1\}$ and not $\{1,2\}$. Similarly, $\{2\}\cap A=\{2\}$. I think you've misunderstood what intersection, $\cap$, means. The intersection of two sets is the set of elements that are in both sets, e.g. $\{1,2,3,4\}\cap \{2,4,5\}=\{2,4\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This restriction fixes $3$ elements in the counting argument. So in general the answer would be $$2^{N-3}$$ as each of the numbers $4, ..., N$ can be chosen to be included in or excluded from $B$. In particular, we know $1, 2 \in B$ and $ 3 \not \in B$.

For your particular case $N=5$ so we have $2^ {5-3}=2^2=4$ subsets. These allowed subsets are:
$ \{1, 2 \}, \{1,2, 4 \}, \{1, 2, 5 \}, \{ 1,2,4,5\}$

Comment: thanks, now it's clear